# UIScrollView Pagination on rotation

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiscrollview, rotation

I have a UIScrollview with some subviews, on rotation I resize and all looks correct, the problem is that when I rotate even though I have correctly resized everything in viewwillrotate, my scrollview is between two pages.

A single touch on the scrollview aligns everything correctly, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: It'd be better if you post a screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be fixed with setting content offset manually:

```
        [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0) animated:YES];
```